# How to access localhost on my ubuntu laptop from android tablet?

Tags: android, tablet, localhost

I'm developing websites and I want to preview the ones from localhost on my Nexus7.

Comment: Can you add a little more context?  Thanks.

Comment: Really this question is generic to **any** Android device, rather than specific to **Nexis 7**.  How are you connecting?  WiFi, USB, etc.

Comment: What do you mean with localhost, is it 127.0.0.1, then you can't. Other IP addresses of your machin can be seen with the command 'ip addr'.

Comment: like anders say localhost is 127.0.0.1 and can only be reached through the machine itself, you asked this question because you mistake the word localhost with anything that has to do with localnetwork, which is the way to reach "hosts that are local to the network" but you just don't have a clue.

Answer (score 8):

On your Ubuntu machine, find your local IP address. One way of finding this is by using the `ifconfig` terminal command, where it is displayed as `inet addr` under the interface you're currently using to connect to the network. Point the browser on your Nexus 7 to that IP address, and the web page should be displayed.

Comment: A side note to this, just make sure that both the tablet and PC are on the same network.